# order by executed twice with fetch first rows only clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to retrieve the first row of a query like this:

```
    select tbl.a
      from tbl
     where tbl.code = 5
  order by util_test.getPrio(tbl.id)
     fetch first 1 rows only;
```

util_test.getPrio() returns an integer I'm using to order the outcome. 
Because I'm only interested in the best result I'm fetching the first row only.

The query (without 'fetch first') returns only one row, however, util_test.getPrio() contains a dbms_output and if I add 'fetch first 1 rows only' I see the same output 2 times. If I don't, I see the output only one time, like expected.

I'm not really interested in a solution (and I know it's bad from a performance point of view),
I'm just wondering why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `order by` happens before `fetch first ... rows only`. Otherwise you would get any row, not the one with the lowest value returned by `util_test.getPrio(tbl.id)`.

In other words, you might have two rows that qualify the `where` condition. Those are sorted, then the first one is taken.

**EDIT**

In Oracle, `fetch first ... rows only` is internally rewritten as a window function. Along this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT *
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY <HERE>) rn
          FROM tbl
         WHERE tbl.code = 5
       )
 WHERE rn <= 1
```

If you like, you can try the "old" Oracle appraoch and see if the issue remains. This works using the `rownum` pseudo-column instead of the window function `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT *
             , rownum rn
          FROM tbl
         WHERE tbl.code = 5
         ORDER BY <HERE>
       )
 WHERE rn <= 1
```

Unfortunately, the "old" approach was still faster than the `fetch first` last time I checked :/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I just edited my question. The query itself only returns one row in this case anyway. Still I get the debug twice... I was just wondering if fetch first ran some part of the query twice.

Comment: thank you! Exactly the explanation i was hoping for.

Comment: @ch1ll I hope you noticed my mistake to remove the ORDER BY altogether. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I thank that a function in the `order by` is going to be called each time it is referenced -- although this might not be true of deterministic functions.

I would expect the function to be called about n * log(n) times, where `n` is the number of rows returned by the rest of the query.

This is easily fixed by using a subquery:

```
select a
from (select tbl.a, util_test.getPrio(tbl.id) as pri
      from tbl
      where tbl.code = 5
     ) t
order by pri
fetch first 1 rows only;
```

Note that this will call the function once per row generated by the subquery.

Comment: that's how I did it in the end ;)